# Using grunt on a large Javascript project with multiple subdirectories

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, organization

I have a Javascript project with multiple subdirectories, each its own individual project. I could just use one massive Gruntfile with different tasks for each project, but I'd rather have a Gruntfile in each subfolder. A typical file structure would be this

```
main_folder/
    project_1
        src
            js/
        dist/
        doc/
        Gruntfile.js
        package.json
    package.json
    node_modules/
```

And then repeat the file structure for each project

Here is my Gruntfile inside project_1

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {



    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
                dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

It has fewer tasks than I will use, but the errors are still there. Whenever I try to run grunt, I get the error message `Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?`, even though I have it installed in node_modules.

How can I specify the location of node_modules, or do I have to reinstall node_modules inside each folder?

Comment: I see that you have another `package.json` inside your subdirectories, but no `node_modules` directory with them. Maybe you can include the `grunt-contrib-uglify` inside the subdirectories' `package.json devDependencies`, then run `npm install` from inside the subdirectories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can still keep everything in the same place if you tell Grunt more explicitly where to find your plugins.  For example, here's a bit from one of my Gruntfiles:

```
grunt.loadTasks tasks for tasks in grunt.file.expand '../node_modules/grunt-*/tasks'
```

*As a side note: I faced exactly the same choice you did, but made the opposite choice: a single Gruntfile for the whole project and created a symlink to it from each project sub-directory.  It's turned out to be a very easy way to keep things together in one place, and side-steps a lot of confusing issues like the one you're facing.*

Comment: OK, but then I would have to have hundreds of nearly identical tasks, just with a different name and folder. Is there a way around that, where I could use just one or two tasks?

Comment: I should clarify... I add a symlink to the Gruntfile for each project so that it's working directory is based in each project's own subdirectory, but there's still just one Gruntfile.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to solve this might be the use of [subgrunt](https://github.com/tusbar/grunt-subgrunt). It let's you configure various targets for your subprojects and has the option `npmInstall`, which "Determines wether npm install will be ran for the sub-project (thus installing dev dependencies)."